# Xcode 11 Swift 5 Updating a label in the non-main thread

Tags: swift5, xcode11

Apologies if this has been answered but I've tried and failed miserably to find it.

I'm very new to "real" programming despite a long time working with "simple" languages such as VB, VBA.

I have a function that retrieves data from a URL and I want to update a UILabel when it's finished. I think I finally got my head around async calls and I thought I was doing the right thing calling the main thread to update the label but I'm still getting an error.

the error is **UILabel.text must be used from main thread only**

```
getBGs { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error) error occured")
        } else  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let today = Date()
                let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
                formatter1.dateFormat = "E d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                self.getBGsText.text = "Retrieved \(BGs?.count) at \(formatter1.string(from: today))"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it help but you can change your code so you build the text string and put it into a variable before calling DispatchQueue.main.async and then use it inside the closure `self.getBGsText.text = textValue`. That way you at least do less work on the main thread.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That makes a lot of sense thank you. I’ve done it but still get the same error when I try to set the text to the label

Comment: i have no idea why but changing the optional to an explicit in the string seems to have fixed it.